# Yeoman angular-generator grunt serve:dist giving error

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

My gruntfile.js has been created by Yeoman angular-generator. When I run this in development site using grunt serve, it works fine, but using **grunt serve:dist** it does not work. The site is opened but views link do not work only Home link works, I think it is because other view templates are not reachable.

Gives following error after running grunt serve:dist

Running "ngtemplates:dist" (ngtemplates) task
File .tmp/templateCache.js created.

> > Usemin has not created uglify.generated yet!

My Gruntfile.js is below:

https://github.com/charutiwari04/dashboard/blob/master/Gruntfile.js

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: No file at given link !!!

Comment: Hello, That problem got resolved. All files were not minimized thats why error. Thank you..